# fastest way to recognize if an array has changed

Tags: php, arrays

I would like to compare whether an array has changed between the start and end of a script.  Types of values (boolean, string) will not change, only the values themselves.  One way is obviously:

```
if($array1 != $array2){ //we have a change }
```

But I am wondering if doing a serialize() first on both would be faster, OR if there's a method I am not aware of.

Comment: why would you think converting both things to a string and comparing the strings - would be faster than php alone comparing 2 variables of the same type? Alternatively sounds like a logifc problem - why not `$changed = true` or `$array1['updated'] = true` whenever you update something and test the value of that boolean.

Comment: Use [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) or array_diff_assoc following your needs.

Comment: @Debflav `array_diff` should be overkill in this situation - you can break the check if you find one different value, so overall execution time should be less than checking all values

Comment: Serialize both arrays will loop through both, the same happens with array_diff, and compare operator (==), a "faster" way to do it would be to keep the array in an object that has a property state

Comment: @kingkero : It depends on the situation. If the array is not huge array_diff() do the trick.

Comment: @AD7six the reason I cannot is that there are too many places in code I'd have to go back on.  And debflav I will benchmark array_diff or _assoc - I have heard of those functions but not used them.

Comment: @SamuelFullman: Replace your check by a function, then you can easily swap out the code if you find a better performing version in a single place. No need to change the code everywhere. That's one of the reason functions were invented ;)

Answer (score 1):

Language features are the fastest. Try this:

```
class MyFastClass extends ArrayObject
{
    public function append($value)
    {
        parent::append($value); // you can track changes here
    }
}
```